# Can a Man leave his parent's house to go live with his wife?

Tags: halal-haram, husband-wife, parents

**Can a man leave his parents' house to go live with his wife separately.**
Are there any rules defined in Sharia for this or any regulations to be followed.

Comment: Cab the parents afford to live or survive without you? Do they have the ability to live alone if they would be alone?

Comment: See [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/40217/13637)

Comment: From shari'a point of view the husband must care for his wife and be in charge of her and their children, so this basically means staying dependent on the parents is excluded. So staying at the parents house is rather an exception from this perspective.

Comment: We seek effortful questions showing prior research.  Asking about permissibility without indicating a reason it's not the [default ruling](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/36838) is considered [off-topic](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/663).  Please [edit] the question accordingly.  See [How do we answer a question “Is X haram?” when there's no reason to think X is haram?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3305)